# Play 2.1 two consecutive promises 2nd one failed to return

Tags: akka, playframework-2.1

I put two promises in the following order and map promises to string result immediately after getting promises. The 2nd promise result will fail to return. The error happens only in 2nd promise mapping. This is testing under Play 2.1 Java. Is there a better way to solve this?

```
    Promise<String> prom1 = Akka.future(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            // intensive computation
            return "prom1 ret";
        }
    });
    Promise<String> prom2 = Akka.future(new Callable<String>() {
        public String call() {
            // intensive computation
            return "prom2 ret";
        }
    });
    String ret1 = prom1.map(
            new Function<String,String>() {
              public String apply(String str) {
                  return str + " affix";
              }
            }
          ).get();
    String ret2 = prom2.map(
            new Function<String,String>() {
                public String apply(String str) {
                    return str + " affix";
                }
              }
          ).get();
```

**Exception I got:**

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:132) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:128) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [10000 milliseconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:96) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:58) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Await$$anonfun$ready$1.apply(package.scala:86) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.MonitorableThreadFactory$AkkaForkJoinWorkerThread$$anon$3.block(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:173) ~[akka-actor_2.10-2.1.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.managedBlock(ForkJoinPool.java:2803) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```